# Multiple buttons in single page navigating each button to different page in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Please solve this problem in android studio, I am new to app development.
I want to create 3 buttons in a single page and navigate each button to each different page.
I need code for java i.e "Mainactivity.java"
I have declared 3 button id's
I have set everything in app manifest.
I am able to navigate only single button at once but how can I arrange all three buttons for navigation?

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button buttonWRGL = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonWRGL);
    Button buttonHNK = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonHNK);
    Button buttonKZP = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonKZP);

    buttonWRGL.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonHNK.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonKZP.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.buttonWRGL:

            break;
        case R.id.buttonHNK:
            break;
        case R.id.buttonKZP:
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what code you have already written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems unclear, but I suppose that you are asking how to load another layout/activity/fragment by clicking on a button.

Well, it depends on which of the three actions you want to do:

1) in order to load another layout, you need to inflate the new layout in your view; in order to do that you need to clear the actual layout and inflate the new one.
Here's some sample code:

```
//you may change it to whichever layout you used
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

//remove previous view
ll.removeAllViews();

//set the new view
setContentView(R.layout.new_layout);
```

2) in case you want to start a new activity, you need to use a Intent and load it.
Sample code:

```
//create the new intent; it will refer to the new activity
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);

//pass any data to the new activity; cancel this line if you don't need it
intent.putExtra(extra_title, extra)

//start the new activity
startActivity(intent);
```

3) in case you want to change fragment, you need to perform a transaction.
Sample code:

```
//create the new fragment
Fragment newFragment = new MyFragment();

//start a fragment transaction
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

//replace the old fragment with the new
transaction.replace(R.id.frame, newFragment).commit();
```

Hope this helps; if not, try to edit your question in order to clarify what you mean.

---

**EDIT:**

You should add a new OnClickListener to each button, but I would do it differently than you are doing right now.
I would do something like this sample code:

```
buttonWRGL.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity1.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

For each button. In this code, I directly attach a specific OnClickListener to the button; it will contain the intent that you need.
You can copy this in every button, even 10k buttons, you just need to change the activity name inside the intent declaration with the activity that you want to launch.

Comment: Thank you "Tenik" you are somewhat clear to me. I want to open new activity using intent, I am able to open new activity from one button but how can I use intent for all three buttons so that I can open first button to one new activity, second button to another new activity and third button to one more new activity.

Comment: Thank you once again I got a clear idea and will try in the same manner you guided.

Comment: Ok :)
If it works, please thick the answer as "correct" :)

Comment: Thank you very much its working fine, I have set OnClickListener to each button.